# "as was just mentioned" or "as just mentioned"?

Tags: sentence-construction, ellipsis

> A couple of lines earlier: for this reason one can say that the subjects in questions have been influenced by X.
>
> .
>
> .
>
> .
>
> 1. A survey of that kind would show how, **as was just mentioned**, the
>      subjects have been  influenced by X.
> 2. A survey of that kind would show how, **as just mentioned**, the
>      subjects have been influenced by X.

I have frequently seen sentences in the form of sentence 2. That is, they just drop "was/were". But that doesn't sound correct to me, because sentence 2 does not give the passive meaning required.

So are both 1 and 2 equally correct, or 1 prefered?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Strictly speaking, form 1 is probably better, but this kind of elision is common, and the meaning is clear. An active form, "as i just mentioned" would be better yet in some cases.

It is my view that this kind of writing, where the text calls attention to another part of itself, is often overdone and would be better if omitted totally. Sometimes it is needed, or at least it clarifies the writing significantly, and then it should be left in. But when it is pointing out the obvious or the trivial, it can be pruned with advantage.